# Solution for Markowitz problem with Safety-First Ratio

Tags: optimization, portfolio-optimization, markowitz

What is the solution for the following markowitz **unconstrained** problem?
The sum of the entries of the weights vector $w$ should always be requied to sum one? Or if we use the risk-free asset it can be let unconstrained? I thought we should always have the constraint $1^{T}w = 1$. Am I wrong? Anyway I would like the solution for the unconstrained and the constrained problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, still need $1^T w =1 $ (usually only 1 $w_i$ will be 1, the others 0). "Roy's Safety First Criterion" http://www.ams.jhu.edu/~daudley/447/jhuonly/550.447%20SP13%20Wk4A.pdf Page 13, 14

Comment: @noob2 would you have a derivation of the solution?